# ASP.NET MVC3  application with CMS capabilities

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, content-management-system

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC3 and doing an application with CMS capabilities - but have run into some problems.

The basic idea is that all pages are connected to a pagetype, which in turn have a set of properties connected to it.

Works great if I'm only using string values, but I want to be able to type all properties (String, LongString, XhtmlString, Number and TrueFalse).

This is my models that I have come up with.

```
public class Page
{
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public int PageTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public PageType PageType { get; set; }

    public List<PropertyValues> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class PageType
{
    public int PageTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }

    public List<PropertyDefinition> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyDefinition
{
    public int PropertyDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; } // NormalString, LongString, XhtmlString, Number, TrueFalse
}

public class PropertyValues
{
    public int PropertyValueId { get; set; }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public int PropertyDefinitionId { get; set; }

    public string ValueNormalString { get; set; } // input=text
    public string ValueLongString { get; set; } // textarea
    public string ValueXhtmlString { get; set; } // tinymce
    public int ValueNumber { get; set; } // input=text
    public bool ValueTrueFalse { get; set; } // input=checkbox

    public PropertyDefinition Definition { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, when I'm in my View i want to be able to call for example

```
@Page.Property["Whatever"]
```

and get the values. I'm stuck with the above, and don't know how to proceed.

**Edit:**

With some help from the answer I got from Russ, I came up with the following - which works.
Don't know if there is any better solution to the problem.

Any one have any suggestions on how to improve my solution?

**Models:**

```
public class Page
{
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }

    Dictionary<string, object> PageData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            Property result = this.Properties.Find(
                delegate(Property p)
                {
                    return p.Name.Equals(name);
                });

            if (result != null)
            {
                switch (result.PropertyDefinition.Type)
                {
                    case "String":
                        return result.PropertyValue.ValueString;
                    case "LongString":
                        return result.PropertyValue.ValueLongString;
                    case "XHtmlString":
                        return result.PropertyValue.ValueXhtmlString;
                    case "Number":
                        return result.PropertyValue.ValueNumber;
                    case "Boolean":
                        return result.PropertyValue.ValueBoolean;
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            PageData[name] = value;
        }
    }
}

public class PropertyDefinition
{
    public int PropertyDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyValue
{
    public int PropertyValueId { get; set; }
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }

    public string ValueString { get; set; }
    public string ValueLongString { get; set; }
    public string ValueXhtmlString { get; set; }
    public int ValueNumber { get; set; }
    public bool ValueBoolean { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    public Page Page { get; set; }
    public PropertyDefinition PropertyDefinition { get; set; }
    public PropertyValue PropertyValue { get; set; }

    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public int PropertyDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public int PropertyValueId { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public String Index()
    {
        List<Property> properties = new List<Property>();
        Property propertyOne = new Property {
            PropertyId = 1,
            Name = "Title",
            Caption = "Page Title",
            TestPageId = 1,
            PropertyValue = new PropertyValue {
                PropertyValueId = 1,
                PropertyId = 1,
                ValueString = "This is the page title"
            },
            PropertyDefinition = new PropertyDefinition {
                PropertyDefinitionId = 1,
                Name = "String",
                Description = "String (< 255 characters)",
                Type = "String"
            }
        };
        properties.Add(propertyOne);

        Page CurrentPage = new Page
        {
            TestPageId = 1,
            Name = "Testpage",
            Properties = properties
        };


        return CurrentPage["Title"].ToString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the model passed to the strongly typed View is of type `Page`, then it should simply be `@Model.Properties`. So your Razor view looks something like

```
@* set the model for the view to be of type Page *@
@model Page

@* to get the properties *@
@foreach(var prop in Model.Properties)
{
    <p>@prop.PageId</p>
}
```

In order to index into `Properties` collection using a string, I'd recommend using a `Dictionary<string, PropertyDefinition>` instead of a `List<PropertyDefintion>`, or make it a [`KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx).

You might decide to create your own WebViewPage that adds a `Page` property by inheriting from `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` and then setting this as the baseType in the web.config under the Views folder

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <!-- Set your type here below -->
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Configuration"/>
            <add namespace="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for - but still have one issue thou. How to I get the Dictionary to map PropertyDefinition with PropertyValue? If i have a definition with a name of "Test" and type "NormalString" I want to be able to lookup Page().Properties["Test"] and get the value from PropertyValue

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, you are supposed to keep property values in your Model, not in your View.

Read about Model-View-Controller at http://www.asp.net and http://www.manning.com/palermo3/ASP.NETMVC3iA_meap_ch01.pdf.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I think you've misunderstood my question. I want to pass my model into the view calling @model.Property["propertyname"] I was just unclear when I wrote @Page.Property["propertyname"]. I don't know how to bind the models together to be able to pass the Page model with all the properties

Answer (score 0):

Have you considering looking at existing CMS application code for inspiration. You may want to look at projects such as Orchard or even Oxite which is no longer actively developed but can still give insight.

Comment: Yes I have, but I'm having trouble finding what I'm looking for. Been trying to get this to work on my own for a couple of weeks before asking here :)